# How to set vb.net selectedindex of combobox bound to arraylist

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've searched and found many answers, but am unable to cause a specific combobox item to be shown as part of displaying a record in a form.

The form contains a combobox with a DropDownList style.  I loaded it using an ArrayList exactly as described [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) .

After the combobox is loaded, I'm reading a database record, and I want the combobox's `DisplayMember` item to be displayed for a database value equal to that item's `ValueMember`.  I've tried everything I can think of, but the first `DisplayMember` item is always displayed.  I've tried:

```
cboVehicleBodyType.SelectedIndex = cboVehicleBodyType.FindString(clsVehicle.fk_body_type)

cboVehicleBodyType.SelectedItem = clsVehicle.fk_body_type
```

...and several other variants, without luck.

The combobox contains approx. 180 body types and their primary keys (loaded from a BodyType table), and the database record for a vehicle contains the body type primary key (named foreign key in the Vehicle record).

How can I get the correct body type to be displayed in the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

To keep with the example from MSDN, you can select an item like this:

```
  Private Sub SelectItem(box As ComboBox, stateKey As String)
    For curItem As Integer = 0 To box.Items.Count - 1
      If DirectCast(box.Items(curItem), USState).ShortName = stateKey Then
        box.SelectedIndex = curItem
        Return
      End If
    Next
  End Sub


  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim USStates As New ArrayList()
    USStates.Add(New USState("Alabama", "AL"))
    USStates.Add(New USState("Washington", "WA"))
    USStates.Add(New USState("West Virginia", "WV"))
    USStates.Add(New USState("Wisconsin", "WI"))
    USStates.Add(New USState("Wyoming", "WY"))
    ComboBox1.DataSource = USStates

    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "LongName"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName"
    SelectItem(ComboBox1, "WY")
  End Sub
```

This code iterates through the elements and looks for the key value. FindString looks for the display value that will not your key.